# thread vs. subroutine. When to use what?

Tags: multithreading, subroutine

I think threads and subroutines are not directly comparable, but I'm designing a system that many class instances communicating with each other and I'm not sure how exactly I should do it.

Let's say I have a class that receives a command, execute the command, and return the result. To execute commands, I can make methods to handle them, or I can create threads for each command and forward the message to an appropriate thread and have the thread handle the command.

Is there any criteria to choose a certain design? like real-time, or concurrency issue? An can the number of threads be a problem if it is too large?

Thank you.

Comment: The many-threads approach is called the actor model (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model). I've best seen it employed by Erlang. OS threads are too heavy for the numbers that you are probably looking at (Erlang doesn't use them).

Comment: @NeilLocketz Those days Golang is supposed to be the poster boy for green threads, not Erlang. :-) And, of course, both modern Erlang and Golang runtimes use multiple OS threads (unless disabled by user) for tasklet scheduling.

Comment: @oakad, Not a fan of Go myself :P. Right about the OS threads. I meant that an Erlang process is not (necessarily) running on its own OS thread.

Comment: start with simple methods and measure performance. If it is not sufficient, then you have an option to use threads, but note that acceleration will be less than the number of cores on your computer.